# Create a SQL Database locally

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to learn ADO.NET and such with SQL. However, i'm at home for the winter so I'm away from my school's servers which were configured already. I'm looking to run something like a local sql server and databases to just practice and learn with. I downloaded and installed MS SQL Server 2008 Express, but I don't know what to do with it to get this going. Are there any guides or materials I can reference to figure out how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you download and install the one with advanced tools, so you get SQL Server Management Studio. You can then connect you your server as `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` (assuming default installation) with Windows authentication, and administer it as usual using Management Studio.

Comment: Would that be SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition? It's a much, much larger download, so I'll assume so. I'll check that out, then. Thanks.

Comment: Developer edition is much different from Express with advanced tools.  Express has some limits to it (DB size, processor usage, memory usage, etc) whereas developer edition has the same feature set as Enterprise Edition (except you can't use it for anything other than development.)  Express will probably do you fine, but if you start getting more serious about working with databases, developer edition is an excellent investment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as learning ADO.NET, binding, etc., take a look at some of these free online videos. They run about 5-15 minutes, some may be longer.

[MSDEV Videos](http://www.msdev.com)

[MSDN How-Do-I videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466226.aspx)

You didn't mention a language but MSDN has pages for VB and C#. These videos cover some SQL Server stuff as well as how to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would definitely be to download and use the SQL Server Management Studio Express - that gives you a nice UI to create and work with databases and database objects.

If you can't download SSMS Express, you always do have the `sqlcmd` utility at your fingertips - it's a command-line driven utility which allows you to send T-SQL command to your SQL Server - check out the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx) on how to use it in detail.

You could e.g. create a new database using:

```
sqlcmd -S server1\SQLExpress -U SqlUserAccount -P SqlPassword -Q "CREATE DATABASE (yourdatabasename)"
```

and you can also do any other T-SQL statement directly from the command line.